# Dojo: tooltip delay

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

Using this code to attache Dojo-tooltips elements:

```
new Tooltip({
    connectId: 'app-container',
    selector: '*',
    position: ['above-centered', 'after'],
    getContent: function(matchedNode){
        return matchedNode.getAttribute('tooltipText');
    }
});
```

And then this code to set tooltip text:

```
<span class="tag" tooltipText="Show tests tagged 'workforce'">Workforce</span>
```

The problem is that all tooltips have half of a second delay (which looks like a value by default for Dojo), and makes the interface looks laggy. Tried to overwrite it using CSS:

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 0s !important;
animation-duration: 0s !important;
```

But this didn't work. [Dojo Reference page](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Tooltip.html) doesn't have any info as well.

Is there any way to remove this delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page does have info. The `showDelay` is by default 400ms. You can change it by passing your own value.

And, there are some problems in your code as far as I can tell. You need to pass the tooltip text in the `Tooltip` object which you have not done. See the fiddle(link below).

```
new Tooltip({
    connectId: 'app-container',
    selector: '*',
    showDelay: 0,
    position: ['above-centered', 'after'],
    getContent: function(matchedNode){
        return matchedNode.getAttribute('tooltipText');
    }
});
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6h1d4fa/).

Comment: `showDelay` worked like a charm. Everything else (including text) seemed to work fine.